# Possible to reliably open AND edit an NSKeyedArchiver's archive?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nskeyedarchiver

I'm using something like the code below to save an NSDictionary of objects to the device. Is there a way to open this archive, drill down into the Dictionary items that it contains and, *ideally*, edit the data? My guess is no, not reliably, as the optimization done when saving makes the archive difficult to interpret...at least it appears that way when opened with something like **Property List Editor**. For instance, if some of my objects share a similar NSString it appears that said NSString is only archived once...altering the structure of the NSDictionary from what I had been expecting.

```
- (BOOL)writeDataToFile {
 NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
 NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
 [archiver encodeObject:myDictionary forKey:kDataKey];
 [archiver encodeInteger:kDataFileVersion forKey:kDataVersionKey];
 [archiver finishEncoding];
 BOOL success = [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
 [archiver release];
 [data release];
 return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is "should you?" ... probably not.

Sure, you could parse the file format, but that format is an implementation detail that *could* change and it's just not worth it.

Why are you trying to do this? Are you trying to make incremental edits a la Core Data + sqlite? Would just plain old sqlite itself solve your issue?

Comment: I was just curious if maybe I was overlooking, or wasn't aware, of some *thing* or some *tool* that could parse these files. Why? Mostly to test how an application responded to different types of data in the archive. Nothing related to CD or SQLite.

Comment: That's a rather unhelpful answer to a valid request. I, for instance, need to compare two versions of such a plist file (i.e. the "layout" and "elements" files created by Xcode's Core Data schema editor. In this case, comparing the raw plist files, even when turned into textual plists, is not working well, as many IDs may have changed even if only little changes were made to the model. I need to see the object layout of these archived objects in order to tell what actualy got changed.

Comment: The fact remains the actual internal coding of these files is an implementation detail that could change from one OS version to the next. It's unlikely it will but it's a bad idea to try and parse it manually and outright foolish to try to write it back out again. You need to know the data structure and the names of its keys ahead of time to have a chance of doing this safely. Even then, the *real* class that unarchives it may do something internally to archives created for an earlier version of the class. **BAD IDEA.**